# Command not being invoked after calling update

Tags: elm

Building on the [Elm navigation tutorial](https://www.elm-tutorial.org/en/07-routing/10-navigation.html), I needed to execute a command to fetch additional data once navigating to my `CategoryRoute`.

My `View.elm` looks something like this:

```
view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
    div []
        [ page model ]


page : Model -> Html Msg
page model =
    case model.categories of
        RemoteData.Success categories ->
            case model.currentRoute of
                CategoryListRoute ->
                    CategoryList.view categories

                CategoryRoute id ->
                    let maybeCategory =
                             categories
                                |> SubCategories
                                |> flatten
                                |> filter (\category -> category.id == id)
                                |> head
                        _ = update (OnCategorySelected id) model
                    in
                        case maybeCategory of
                            Just category ->
                                Category.view category

                            Nothing ->
                                notFound
```

You'll notice that I'm calling `update` with the `OnCategorySelected` message myself when the `currentRoute` changes to the `CategoryRoute`.

My `Update.eml` looks something like this:

```
update : Msg -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
update msg model =
    case msg of

        OnArticlesFetch response ->
            let
                _ = log "got response" response
            in
                ( { model | articles = response }, Cmd.none)

        OnLocationChange location ->
                    let
                        newRoute =
                            parseLocation location
                    in
                        ( { model | currentRoute = newRoute }, Cmd.none )

        OnCategorySelected id ->
            ( model, (getArticles model.tenant id) )
```

And finally, my `Commands.eml` looks like so:

```
getArticles : String -> String -> Cmd Msg
    getArticles tenant id =
        let
            url =
                "https://" ++ tenant ++ ".my.api"
            _ = log "getArticles for " id
        in
            Http.post url (Http.jsonBody (encoder id)) decoder
                |> RemoteData.sendRequest
                |> Cmd.map OnArticlesFetch
```

I was expecting that once I'll call `update OnCategorySelected`, it will in turn invoke the `getArticles` function, which is passed a `Cmd Msg`, which I had thought will be invoked once the response comes in.

The problem I'm facing is that while `update OnCategorySelected` and `getArticles` seem to get invoked (as indicated by the log printouts `log "getArticles for " id`), I'm seeing no outgoing HTTP calls, no errors, no results and no `log "got response" response` printouts.

I'm confused as to what am I doing wrong here and what's the pattern for actually fetching more data as one navigates to a page in Elm...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Elm is a pure language where side effects are relegated to the framework. Calling the update function does not actually perform any work itself. It simply returns a value that can be handed off to the Elm framework directing it to interact with the outside world. That means when you call update from within the `page` function and discard the result, nothing happens.

*One thing that can cause confusion is that `Debug.log` actually does get called and prints to the console, which violates the aforementioned purity of the language. It's just a magic function which exists only for debugging so hopefully it doesn't cause too much confusion.*

You should instead be handling the `RemoteData.Success` case in the update function after parsing the route in the `OnLocationChange` case and returning a result which includes the `getArticles` result Cmd.

```
OnLocationChange location ->
    let
        newRoute =
             parseLocation location

        cmd =
            case newRoute of
                CategoryRoute id ->
                    getArticles model.tenant id

                _ ->
                    Cmd.none
    in
        ( { model | currentRoute = newRoute }, cmd )
```

Comment: That did it. Thanks @Chad Gilbert ,  that `Debug.log` indeed threw me off.